# ecryptfs-mount-private расшифровать домашний каталог с внешнего накопителя

Tags: ubuntu

Имеется hdd с ubuntu 17.04, подключенный через usb, необходимо расшифровать домашний каталог находясь в другой системе с аналогичными настройками, имя пользователя и UID совпадают. 
Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop не помог. Менял путь в файле Private.mnt на текущий (с учётом пути подключенного устройства). ecryptfs-mount-private не дал результатов.

**UPD: 1**

```
sudo mkdir /home/alexandr1
sudo chmod /home/alexandr1
sudo '/media/alexandr/16663f38-1066-4705-8799-0ab393b5acfc/home/alexandr/Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop' 
/media/alexandr/16663f38-1066-4705-8799-0ab393b5acfc/home/alexandr/Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop: 1: /media/alexandr/16663f38-1066-4705-8799-0ab393b5acfc/home/alexandr/Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop: [Desktop: not found
/media/alexandr/16663f38-1066-4705-8799-0ab393b5acfc/home/alexandr/Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop: 2: /media/alexandr/16663f38-1066-4705-8799-0ab393b5acfc/home/alexandr/Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop: Your: not found
/media/alexandr/16663f38-1066-4705-8799-0ab393b5acfc/home/alexandr/Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop: 3: /media/alexandr/16663f38-1066-4705-8799-0ab393b5acfc/home/alexandr/Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop: Your: not found
/media/alexandr/16663f38-1066-4705-8799-0ab393b5acfc/home/alexandr/Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop: 7: /media/alexandr/16663f38-1066-4705-8799-0ab393b5acfc/home/alexandr/Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop: Security: not found
/media/alexandr/16663f38-1066-4705-8799-0ab393b5acfc/home/alexandr/Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop: 8: /media/alexandr/16663f38-1066-4705-8799-0ab393b5acfc/home/alexandr/Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop: X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=ecryptfs-utils: not found
```

При запуске 
Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop из ГУИ запрашивает пароль, потом на панели программ появляется знак вопроса, через некоторое время исчезает. Результата нет.

**UPD: 2**

взято [здесь](http://forum.ubuntu.ru/index.php?topic=254398.0), не помогло.

```
sudo ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase '/media/alexandr/16663f38-1066-4705-8799-0ab393b5acfc/home/alexandr/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase' 
[sudo] пароль для alexandr: 
Passphrase: 
b6e4e*********************b6e19e
sudo ecryptfs-recover-private 
INFO: Searching for encrypted private directories (this might take a while)...
find: «/run/user/1000/gvfs»: Отказано в доступе
sudo ecryptfs-recover-private /media/alexandr/16663f38-1066-4705-8799-0ab393b5acfc/home/.encryptfs/alexandr/.Private
[sudo] пароль для alexandr: 
INFO: Searching for encrypted private directories (this might take a while)...
find: «/run/user/1000/gvfs»: Отказано в доступе
```

**UPD: 3**

Отправил в [багрепорт убунту](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ecryptfs-utils/+bug/1718410), кто поможет дополнить и проголосовать, тому спасибо.